# Ambiguous redirect / can't stat when trying to write files to USB connected drive

Tags: bash

This is making me go mental. My bash script should take some files one a remote hard drive (connected to my laptop by USB) and then run them through a bunch of scripts on the laptop and them dump the output back on the hard drive. But I cant get it to recognise the USB connected hard drive. It must be the naming of the hard drive but I dont think I can change that really. The important part of the script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

for f in ./Volumes/"Seagate Backup Plus Drive"/SequencingRawFiles/*; do

sampleName=${f##*/};

echo $sampleName;

gzcat $f | ./reformat_sequence_data.rb > 1reformatsequence/${sampleName}.reformat.txt;

done
```

The error message I get is:

```
loop1ForRemoteStoredFiles.sh: line 12: 1reformatsequence/${sampleName}.reformat.txt: ambiguous redirect
gzcat: can't stat: ./Volumes/Seagate (./Volumes/Seagate.gz): No such file or directory
```

Comment: spaces always create havoc when you don't quote variables that include spaces, i.e. `gzcat "$f" | ...` eh? Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

Its OK I've sorted it. I just renamed the hard drive so there were no spaces in the name path. Seems like spaces really create havoc